# WebTextEdit ClientSideEvent Javascript - Can't Eval

Tags: javascript, webtextedit

WebtextEdit ClientSideEvent execute javascript statement on mousemove event. 
I can successfully change the style of another object type on this WebTextEdit ClientSide MouseMove event:

```
document.getElementById("Object2").style.backgroundColor = '#F0F5F7';
```

But when I want to change the style of the WebTextEdit control:

```
document.getElementById("WebTextEdit1").style.backgroundColor = '#F0F5F7';
```

Then nothing happens.

When I execute the script on the same WebTextEdit Clientside for another object which is not a WebtextEdit:

```
Object2.style.border='1px solid #FFE6A0';
```

Then it works. But when I want to change the WebtextEdit Clientside style:

```
WebTextEdit1.style.border='1px solid #FFE6A0';
```

Then I get Error:

```
Can't Eval WebTextEdit1.style.border='1px solid #FFE6A0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the identifier "WebTextEdit1" is not correct. Please check your source for a typo.